# How to handle AngularJS config block errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-module

Hi folks I am new to angular js. I have a module 'ngApp' which depends on a module 'ng-main'. I want to handle errors and exceptions that might be thrown in a config block of 'ng-main' module. I have created a new module 'ng-error' and made 'ngApp' dependent on this module to handle errors and exceptions but it's kind of not catching it.

index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  angular.module('ngApp', ['ng-error', 'ng-main']);
</script>
```

ngErrors.js

```
angular.module('ng-error',[])
 .config(function($provide) {
    $provide.factory('$exceptionHandler', function($injector) {
        return function (exception, cause) {
            console.log(exception);

            // display error message 

        };
    });
});
```

ngMain.js

```
angular.module('ng-main', ['ng-test'])
.config(function(){
  // code with error
});
```

If any errors occurs in this config block it totally fails but I want to manually handle those. Any thoughts or comments on my code?

Comment: AFAIK you cannot do that without fiddling with angular module loading mechanism.

Comment: I agree with your point but is there any better way to manually handle angular bootstrapping errors? I am trying override exceptionHandler so that if any modules after ['ng-error'] fail, it will handle those error and would popup message to user instead of failing and showing blank screen

Comment: Any suggestions or comments guys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, Tried below code and worked. Manually overridden angular bootstrap process and wrapping that code inside try{} catch {} block to handle errors in config block

something like this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    angular.module('ngApp', ['ng-error', 'ng-main']);

   angular.element(document).ready(function() {
     try {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['ngApp']);
     } catch(e) {
       //handle errors
     }
  });
  </script>
```